# I want to close all the form before close the application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form1, from this form1 going to new form2, form2 new form 3... and when I close form1 then application close.but, i want close all form before close application.

Comment: Your grammar is a bit difficult to understand. Do you mean that you want to be able to go through the whole sequence of forms, one at a time, not closing the application until the last form opened has been closed?

Comment: Why do you want to close all forms before closing the application, since the form1 closing will close all the other forms? what is your point here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (and I might not...it's hard to read), what you want is to ensure that closing your first form doesn't close the entire program, and that closing the last form does. If that's the case, then you need to make the following changes:

In your Program.cs file, you'll have some code that looks like `Application.Run(new Form1());`. This passes a `Form` instance to the `Run()` method, and the `Run()` method will automatically return and allow the program to exit when that `Form` instance is closed.

Instead, don't pass anything to `Run()`. Use the parameterless overload: `Application.Run();` You will still have to create the first `Form` instance and show it. E.g. before the call to `Application.Run();` add this:

```
new Form1().Show();
```

Having done that, you now need to call `Application.Exit()` when you actually want the program to end. So in your last form that you show, override `OnFormClosed()`:

```
protected override voide OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

If that's not what you wanted to do, please try to word your question more carefully and explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: so thanks for reading.I think I've found a way to solve. Please ignore if I bother you

Answer (score 2):

you may try

```
foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    f.Close();
}
```

you may adjust it as needed.

see more on [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: sorry, if the question is not clearly.I'm not good English.But, i want close the last form then application close

Comment: that's fine. but you do need to make _some_ effort to improve the wording (based on questions made by others), and to provide appropriate feedback to responders to help them understand if they are on the right track or not.

Answer (score 0):

just write this to show every form

```
Form1 f=new Form1();
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need

Comment: than what do you actually need?

Answer (score 0):

Class System.Windows.Forms.Form has an event [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx). You can handle the closing of forms there.

In form1:

```
public void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  form2.Close()

  // if we have the instances of form3, form4 here, then:
  // form3.Close()
  // form4.Close()
}
```

In form2:

```
public void form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  form3.Close()
}
```

etc.